# i want to display the username in my car index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my controller of cars..
what to add in index method so that we shall get the email of user in our index page

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show]

  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @car = current_user.cars.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
    if @car.save
      format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was  successfully     created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @car.errors, status::unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my index.what to add in index to display the user email in all the cars and all ussers should be abale to see that useremail

```
<%=@car.user.email%>
<div class="row" >
  <% @cars.each do |car| %>
    <div class="col-sm-8" >
      <div class="polaroid center-block" >
        <%=link_to (image_tag car.avatar.url(:medium)),car %>
        <div style="float:right">
        <p><%= link_to  edit_car_path(car) do %>
          <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i>
        <%end %></p>
        |
        <p><%= link_to  car, method: :delete, data: { confirm 'Are you       sure?' } do  %>
        <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        <%end%></p></div>
      </div><br>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
```

i want to display useremail of user who posted the car in my index page.What should i add in controller and my index to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If your car has an association `belongs_to :user` then add this to your controller: `@car = Car.includes(:user).all`

In the index page you can add `<%= car.user.usermail %>`

Comment: its not working because i hve added pagination in my index method like..@cars = Car.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)